# Can CustomListItems explore a tree?

Tags: visual-studio, natvis

I would like to use a .natvis file to display all of the elements in a tree structure as a flat list.

I'm aware of the `TreeItems` expansion described in the .natvis documentation, and have tried to use that, but it seems a bit limited, and difficult to get to work in my situation (Templated node types, nodes which don't contain the actual data, need to cast the nodes to other templated types to get the data, lack of ability to do `Exec` entries or multiple `Item`s per tree node, etc.)

The `CustomListItems` expansion is a lot more flexible in terms of being able to assign variables and execute commands which are evaluated in a loop. But I'm struggling to figure out whether there's a way to explore a tree in `CustomListItems`.  Basically there would have to be some way to maintain a stack of some kind so that I could explore the entire left branch and then pop back up and explore the right branch.  Is there any way to do this in `CustomListItems`?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/debugger/create-custom-views-of-native-objects?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN#natvis-views

Comment: I ran into this exact issue recently. I'm pretty sure that a solution exists, but the documentation we have is insufficient to see it. If you look through the [debugger intrinsic functions to maintain state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/expressions-in-the-debugger#BKMK_Using_debugger_intrinisic_functions_to_maintain_state) you'll find three `TreeTraverse_*` functions that are likely part of the solution. The documentation leaves me puzzled, however.